# UITableView in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, collectionview

I placed a `tableView` inside a `collectionView` and added the delegates. The problem is, that I want to control the data in the different `tableViews` in the `collectionView`.

Every `collectionView` holds a label with the name of the current day (e.g.: "Monday"). Below the label is a `tableView`. In the `tableView` should be displayed different data, based on the index of the `collectionView`.

In my example, every `tableView` has two cells. The `tableView` in the first item of the `collectionView` should display: `cell1: "1"` and `cell2: "2"`, the `tableView` in the second item should display: `cell1: "3"` and `cell2: "4"`.

**I'm currently using the code below:**

```
    import UIKit

class StundenplanCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myHours.append(myH0)
        myHours.append(myH1)
        myHours.append(myH2)
        myHours.append(myH3)
        myHours.append(myH4)
        myHours.append(myH5)

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //MARK: Variables
    var myDays = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag"]
    var myHours: [[String]] = Array() //Array that holds myH1 - myH5
    var myH0 = ["1", "2"]
    var myH1 = ["3", "4"]
    var myH2 = ["5", "6"]
    var myH3 = ["7", "8"]
    var myH4 = ["9", "10"]
    var myH5 = ["Error", "Error"]

    var tableLoop = 0

    var headerColor: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(255/255.0), green: CGFloat(140/255.0), blue: CGFloat(60/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))


    //MARK: Table and Collection View
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myDays.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: StundenplanCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stundenplanCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! StundenplanCollectionViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = myDays[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.backgroundColor = headerColor
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myHours[tableLoop].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: StundenplanTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stundenplanTableCell", for: indexPath) as! StundenplanTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = myHours[/*Here should the indexPath.row of the collectionView item be placed*/][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class StundenplanCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}

class StundenplanTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**Image 1:** Here you can see the first `tableView` in the `collectionView` (first item of `collectionView`):

[image: image 1]

**Image 2:** Here you can see the second tableView in the collectionView (second Item of collectionView):

[image: image 2]

**Image 3:** Storyboard:

[image: image 3]

**Image 4:** Structure of the different objects in the view:

[image: image 4]

**Updated code** (according to the answer by @missionMan - Thanks by the way!):

```
import UIKit

class StundenplanCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

        myHours.append(myH0)
        myHours.append(myH1)
        myHours.append(myH2)
        myHours.append(myH3)
        myHours.append(myH4)
        myHours.append(myH5)

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    //MARK: Variables
    var myDays = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag"]
    var myHours: [[String]] = Array() //Array that holds myH1 - myH5
    var myH0 = ["1", "2"]
    var myH1 = ["3", "4"]
    var myH2 = ["5", "6"]
    var myH3 = ["7", "8"]
    var myH4 = ["9", "10"]
    var myH5 = ["Error", "Error"]

    var headerColor: UIColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(255/255.0), green: CGFloat(140/255.0), blue: CGFloat(60/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))


    //MARK: Table and Collection View
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myDays.count
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stundenplanCollectionViewCell") as? StundenplanCollectionViewCell else { //how can I access the inner tableView? Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView'
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        //set data and reload inner table from outer view controller (StundenplanCollectionViewController according to your code)
        cell.dayItems = myHours[indexPath.row]
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        //...

        return cell
    }


class StundenplanCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var dayItems: [String] = []

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tableView.delegate = self    // <-- set delegates inner table
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension StundenplanCollectionViewCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dayItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: StundenplanTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stundenplanTableViewCell") as? StundenplanTableViewCell)!
        //...
        return cell
    }
}

class StundenplanTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting a table view in each cell if the table view only has two rows? Why not directly add two more labels to your collection view cells?

Comment: Share your screenshot of what you want to designs. After that, I can help you.

Comment: @rmaddy: Because the number of rows can be changed by the user. It's just sample data. In reality something like 11 rows per table is more likely.

Comment: @iDev750: Thanks, I will do that in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add table delegate methods in table cell class
and then you can set data for one day. So each collection cell will have its own table and its own data.

like this:

```
class StundenplanCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell { //<-- outer cell
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerTableView: UITableView! //<-- declare inner table
    var dayItems: [String] = []

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.innerTableView.delegate = self    // <-- set delegates inner table
        self.innerTableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension StundenplanCollectionViewCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dayItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        ...
    }

        ...
```

set data from outer cell of your collectionView in `StundenplanCollectionViewController`

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stundenplanCollectionViewCell") as? StundenplanCollectionViewCell else { //<-- HERE
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    //set data and reload inner table from outer view controller (StundenplanCollectionViewController according to your code)
    cell.dayItems = myH[indexPath.row]
    cell.innerTableView.reloadData()
    ...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your help! But I'm not sure where the second code (public func...) has to be placed. Could you please provide some additional information? I replaced my "cellForItemAt" function in the "StundenplanCollectionViewController" with your public function. But Xcode says: "Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView'".

Comment: You're welcome. Ok the answer has been improved a bit. hope this helps.

Comment: That definitely made some things clearer for me. Thanks a lot! But after all I'm still not able to implement your code in the right way. I updated my code, following your hints and I will add it to the question. It would be great if you could take another look over the code. I just don't get **how to access the tableView inside the ViewController** (StundenplanCollectionViewController).

Comment: hmm sorry, my mistake, error is here: guard let cell = tableView... not tableView it will be collectionView. Answer is updated

Comment: Thanks!!! I should have figured that out by myself. tableView makes no sense in this context. ^^

Comment: Now it's working. I just had to update the function a little bit. CollectionView Cells need to have an indexPath: guard let cell: StundenplanCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stundenplanCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? StundenplanCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to `dequeue` a `UICollectionViewCell` from a `UITableView`?

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right and that was the only problem with the updated code. Now it's working! Thanks.