# Dropdown list in UICollectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dropdown

I am developing a TODOList(iOS application) but there is a problem i.e. how can I add dropdown list is uicollectionview cell.
Means when view did load, collection view loaded, there should be a dropdown in every single cell

Comment: you have to add Uicollectionview as UitableviewCell so its drop down on click esaily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no any inbuilt dropdown functionality in iOS but you can do it by using `UITableView` or by using 3rd party library.

I suggest you to try this. [**DropDown**](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown)

define this globally.

```
let dropDown = DropDown()
```

If you want to customise dropDown you can use this.

```
func customizeDropDown() {
    DropDown.appearance().cellHeight = 40
    DropDown.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    DropDown.appearance().selectionBackgroundColor = Colors.purpleColor
    DropDown.appearance().cornerRadius = 5
    DropDown.appearance().textColor = Colors.NavTitleColor
    DropDown.appearance().shadowColor = (UIColor.init(hexString: "1AD691")?.withAlphaComponent(0.0))!
    DropDown.appearance().shadowOpacity = 0.9
    DropDown.appearance().shadowRadius = 0
    DropDown.appearance().animationduration = 0.25
}
```

In `cellForItemAt` you need to add action on your dropdown button like this.

```
cell.btnDropdown.tag = indexPath.item
cell.btnDropdown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnDropDownTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Once you tapped on any button from `UICollectionViewCell` below method will call where you need to pass `anchorView`.

```
@IBAction func btnDropDownTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dropDown.anchorView = sender // The view to which the drop down will appear on
    self.dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: sender.bounds.height) //Top of drop down will be below the anchorView

    self.dropDown.dataSource = ["First", "Last", "Second", "Third"] // Static array you need to change as per your requirement
    self.dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        print(item) // **NOTE: I AM JUST PRINTING DROPDOWN SELECTED VALUE HERE, YOU NEED TO GET `UICollectionViewCell` HERE YOU NEED TO SET VALUE INSIDE CELL LABEL OR YOU CAN SET SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE IN YOUR MODEL AND RELOAD COLLECTIONVIEW**

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    self.dropDown.show()
}
```

If you have `UITextField` in your `UICollectionViewCell` then you can try this code inside `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate.

**NOTE: I AM JUST PRINTING DROPDOWN SELECTED VALUE HERE, YOU NEED TO GET `UICollectionViewCell` HERE YOU NEED TO SET VALUE INSIDE CELL LABEL OR YOU CAN SET SELECTED DROPDOWN VALUE IN YOUR MODEL AND RELOAD COLLECTIONVIEW**

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't have any native control for drop downs.You can use pickers instead.
See like below :

[image]
 Here is the code to add pickerView.

```
let picker: UIPickerView
picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self

let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
toolBar.translucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")

toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

textField1.inputView = picker
textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

There are lots of libraries added to github for cool picker controls:
[Actionsheet PickerView](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)
[Selectionmenu](https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps to perform your operation

1. Add UITableView in UICollectionViewCell.
2. Make the hidden property of UITableView to true

   collectionViewCell.dropDownTableView.isHidden=true
3. When the user select option to display dropdown, reload UITableView data and set hidden property of UITableView to false.

[How to add UITableView to UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610540/uitableview-in-uicollectionview)